# What model Peugeot is this?

Tags: wheels, peugeot

Anyone know what model this bike is?

I am trying to replace the front wheel of my fg/ss converted vintage Peugeot road bike. I've measured the spacing at 98mm, but because I don't know the correct year, I'm not sure if that is the correct spacing. Sheldon Brown lists 96mm as a common front fork spacing for an older french bike. The rear wheel had been replaced with a Wheel Master LP18 700 track wheel with 120 spacing. Also, most internet wheel listings don't even list the spacing.

Will this wheel fit: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Wheel-Masters-Wheel-Front-700-622X14-Wei-Lp18-Black-Msw-36-Aly-Qr-Black-Dti2-0Sl-/184149905030?_trksid=p2349526.m4383.l4275.c1#viTabs_0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Is it more important to you to know the model of the bike, or how to get a compatible wheel? Try and keep the question specific

Comment: by the way: it might be useful to add a photo of the front fork since you're asking about replacing the front wheel, just a suggestion :)

Comment: I just edited my post to include a pic with the front fork. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes the wheel should fit assuming you have a 'normal' road bike fork installed. I've built maybe a 200 bikes and never had the front wheel spacing be an issue (only axle diameter was an issue when trying to install solid 10mm axle wheels into quick release forks (the solid 10mm axle won't fit in them).

If the spacing does differ a tiny bit you should be able to get away with it by bending the fork legs outwards a bit whilst installing the wheel (keep in mind this might be approx 1mm difference, so it's elastic deformation aka non-permanent bending).

The 2mm difference between your measured spacing and Sheldon brown's suggested standard size shouldn't be an issue. If the wheel is a tiny bit too wide you bend out the fork 2mm (elastic deformation once again), if it's a tiny bit too narrow you can clamp it down using the quick release or nut (if using solid axle).

Even with carbon forks this amount of flexing (when installing the wheel), shouldn't be an issue.

Regarding what model/year bike this is. I wouldn't know but it shouldn't matter if your question is only about front wheel compatibility. Some older bikes use 27 inch wheels but assuming you have the original fork installed on the bike (since the rear wheel you currently have installed is 28" and appears to align just fine with the brake pads of your current calipers) any 28" front wheel should be compatible whilst keeping your original brakes. You might need to adjust your brake pads a bit (their height) after installing the new wheel.

Comment: Its a French bike so seems reasonable that it would have a French wheel size.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus do old French road bikes' wheel sizes differ from other countries' road bikes' as far as you know? If so how big would the difference in dropout width be approximately? I've worked on quite a few Peugeot frames and I never had issues installing different wheels into the frame ..

Comment: I'm talking about rim diameter - on an older bike you may expect it to have '27inch' wheels, but a French Peugeot may well have 700c rims. AFAIK, hubs widths are pretty standard internationally.

Comment: Concur - 2mm on the front OLD is within tolerance for a 100mm OLD wheel.  Consider it as "preload-pressure"